# Is Beach Buggy Racing 2 Haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I have given up playing video games. However I still play one game for entertainment. BBR2 is a racing game. So far it doesn't contain any major Haram elements such as killing, gambling, nudity , murder, shirk, etc. ..but it still has :

1. Animated Characters
2. Music  ( I disable the music though )

Is this game Haram  ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the animated creatures. If they look like real human and have characteristics of have human like nose mouth full facial features it can be Haram. Otherwise it is halal. Spending to much time (like missing salat) is not permissable in Islam. Allah knows the best.